# Get IIS log location via powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, logging

I'm writing a script that I'd like to be able to easily move between IIS servers to analyze logs, but these servers store the logs in different places. Some on C:/ some on D:/ some in W3SVC1, some in W3SVC3. I'd like to be able to have powershell look this information up itself rather than having to manually edit this on each server. (Yeah, I'm a lazy sysadmin. #automateallthethings.)

Is this information available to PowerShell if I maybe pass the domain to it or something?

Comment: For W3SVC*, you can check the website ID's and append them to "W3SVC" to get corresponding log locations.

Answer (score 17):

I found this to work for me since I want to know all of the sites log directory.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

foreach($WebSite in $(get-website))
    {
    $logFile="$($Website.logFile.directory)\w3svc$($website.id)".replace("%SystemDrive%",$env:SystemDrive)
    Write-host "$($WebSite.name) [$logfile]"
    }
```

Comment: Up there 'w3scv' should be 'w3svc'.Can't edit because it's not enough characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$sitename = "mysite.com"
$site = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$sitename
$id = $site.id
$logdir = $site.logfile.directory + "\w3svc" + $id
```

Thanks for [Chris Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343005/chris-harris) for putting the website ID idea in my head. I was able to search around better after that and it led me to the WebAdministration module and examples of its use.

Answer (score 0):

Nice... I updated your script a little bit to Ask IIS for the log file location.

```
    param($website = 'yourSite')

Import-Module WebAdministration

$site = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$website
$id = $site.id
$logdir = $site.logfile.directory + "\w3svc" + $id

$time = (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"(Get-Date).addminutes(-30))
# Location of IIS LogFile
$File = "$logdir\u_ex$((get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")).log"
# Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
$Log = Get-Content $File | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }
# Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
$Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")
# Count available Columns, used later
$Count = $Columns.Length
# Strip out the other rows that contain the header (happens on iisreset)
$Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like "*500 0 0*"}
# Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
#Set-Variable -Name IISLog -Scope Global
$IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"
# Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
  $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
  $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
}
# Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
  $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
  $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
  for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
    $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
    $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
  }
  $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
  }
  $IISLog | select @{n="DateTime"; e={Get-Date ("$($_.date) $($_.time)")}},csuristem,scstatus | ? { $_.DateTime -ge $time }
```