# Check IIS logFile.period on remote server with Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, logging

I need to check the IIS log settings of about 100 servers.  I'm running PS 5, and I've figured out that this gives me the settings for the local server:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites

Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name logFile.period
```

What do I need to do in order to run the same thing on remote servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSRemoting is what you are asking about.

This is a well-documented (using a GUI and PowerShell) thing and articles and sample code are all over the web.

['use remoting to get IIS logs'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=use%20remoting%20to%20get%20IIS%20logs&form=ANNTH1&refig=c220a23d444c470487982267a0355285&sp=-1&pq=use%20remoting%20to%20get%20iis%20log&sc=0-27&qs=n&sk=&cvid=c220a23d444c470487982267a0355285)

[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7)
Runs commands on local and remote computers.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName 'IIS' -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
    Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name logFile.period
}
```

How to retrieve IIS HTTP logs remotely

[Using IIS Manager for Remote Administration](https://theitbros.com/using-iis-manager-for-remote-administration)

[Use PowerShell to Collect, Store, and Parse IIS Log Data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-collect-store-and-parse-iis-log-data)

Get IIS log location via powershell?
[Get IIS log location via powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784883/get-iis-log-location-via-powershell)